# ParametricRegion in Region produces misshapen result

Tags: plotting, regions, parametric-functions

Prompted by an answer to [question 170254](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269072/1063), I considered

```
R = ParametricRegion[{{Cos[p] r Sin[t], r Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[t] r}, 
        1 <= r <= 2 && 0 <= t <= π/2 && 0 <= p <= π/2}, {r, t, p}];
Region[R, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image: plot]

which looks reasonable.  However, seen from a different `ViewPoint`, it is not.  Modest changes to `ViewPoint` do not change this appearance.

```
Region[R, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black},
    ViewPoint -> {-3, -1, 1/2}]
```

[image: bad plot]

The interior surface is misshapen. Have I overlooked something, or is this a bug?

As J.M. noted in a comment, this looks like the result of insufficient sampling. Yet, I would expect the appearance of the region to be the same in the y - z plane as in the x - z plane due to symmetry.  Incidentally, `PlotPoints` is not an accepted option for `Region`.

Comment: `Region[]` sometimes produces pictures where the sampling is insufficient; you'd see similar things with `(Boundary)DiscretizeRegion[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for this insight, as well as for correcting the title.  Is there a way to increase sampling?  `PlotPoints` is not accepted as an Option.  By the way, I would expect the appearance of the region to be the same in the y - z plane as in the x - z plane due to symmetry

Comment: That I do not know; it sounds like a good thing to append to your question.

Comment: Strangely, setting the variables to some values (0 will do) before calling ```ParametricRegion[]``` results in a much smoother curve.